# How to get longer taskbar buttons?

Tags: windows, windows-10, laptop, taskbar, 4k-resolution

By default, the buttons for opened applications on the taskbar look like this:

[image]

However, an odd thing happened.  I have a laptop with a 4k screen.  For work, I plug it into a dock which connects to two 1080p screens.  If the laptop was on prior to plugging it into the dock, the buttons on the 1080p screens look much longer (see below) - showing the entire title of the window.  If I reboot with the dock plugged in, the buttons revert to their default state.

I really like the longer taskbar buttons.  Is there anyway to make it a default?

P.S. Currently to achieve this, I take the laptop off the dock, reboot, wait for Windows to come up and then reconnect to the dock.  Kind of annoying.

[image]

Comment: By default, the taskbar are only icons, not text. But what you want is a registry setting. You can set the maximum length for a button. I Just don't know what the regkey is so this is a comment, not an answer. I don't have time to look it up right now, but if you google for it, you will find it.

Answer (score 5):

You could try the following steps:

1. Press **Win+R** to open Run window and insert **regedit.exe** to open **Registry Editor**
2. Go to the following Registry key.

**Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics**

3. On the right, modify or create a new **string (REG_SZ) value** ***MinWidth***. Change its value data from the default 38 to a greater value. Valid range is from 38 to 500.
4. Reboot your machine and the width of taskbar button will become longer
5. Attaching my test result for your reference

[Registry Key info](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E0aI7.jpg)

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4KcMh.jpg)

Answer (score 2):

**How to Change the Width of the Taskbar buttons**

**Start > Settings > System** on the left panel, click **Display** then in the right section, under **Scale and layout** change the scaling to fit your needs.

Lets me know if this helps